# Passing a value to a search bar

Tags: javascript, python, searchbar

I was trying to figure out a way to use the search bar of a web site without opening the webpage.

To be more precise, let us say we talk about [stackoverflow.com](http://StackOverflow). Using some GET operation it is possible to get the HTML content of it, and after looking it up to figure out that it has a **search menu**.

Is there a nice way to pass a value to the search menu, using some request!? My goal is to read the result of the search, again by asking for the HTML code.
I would prefer an idea in **Python** or **JavaScript**.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a general solution. Two things:

- With python, you can use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) lib to send your GET requests and get the response back. Then you will treat this response with the appropriate tool (response could be json, xml, html...)
- To discover how to build your request, check if the website provide an documented API (*example here with [stackexchange](http://api.stackexchange.com/)*). If it doesn't, try to use the inspector of your browser to discover how the search request is sent when you use the search-bar.